# opportunity closure delay reason if the close date is extended

Tags: validation-rule, administration

I am trying to write a validation rule on opportunity.
scenario is  when an opportunity is created there will be a close date filled which is mandatory. If the close date is extended a field with **delay reason** is mandatory (which is Picklist ). For this I have written the Validation rule which is

```
AND((PRIORVALUE( CloseDate ) < CloseDate ),
(NOT ISCHANGED( Opportunity_closure_delays__c )))
```

But when the opportunity is again extended the **delay reason** may be the same from the picklist or may not be. We need to show error message saying please check the delay reason.
The above code is showing error when we select the same reason if close Date is extended but if I select  other value from the pick list record is getting saved.
Please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It basically means that the picklist value has changed and hence is allowing you to save the record. What is the expected behavior here? Your code seems to be working as designed

Comment: Hi Sid,
If the opportunity is extended and the delay reason is already specified it should show error saying please update the delay reason which may be previous one or new one

Comment: your problem is intractable without additional fields for user to indicate that on close date extension, the delay reason is the same - which you will then need to clear in an @future method

Comment: Little confused now - the scenario which you mentioned in the comment already seems to be working as per your formula - if the reason is already populated and is not changed, but the Opportunity is extended, it does throw an error - is there something i am missing here?